# Is the assumption $y \in C^2$ necessary for the Euler method to be of order $p=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

In my Intro to numerical analysis course, we did the following.

We stated the initial value problem $\dot{y}=\lambda y+f$, where $f \in C[0,\infty)$, and developed the Euler method. Then proved that if $y \in C^2$ then the method is convergent with order $p=1$. Yet the problem statement solely implies that $y$ is differentiable, which is far from being $C^2$.

Is the assumption necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~flaherje/pdf/ode2.pdf):

> The assumption that $\ddot{y}$ exists is not necessary. A proof without this
>   assumption appears in Hairer, Nørsett, Wanner. Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I: Nonstiff Problems.